# Python3 tkinter multiple arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, widget, tkinter, arguments

I now know that to make a widget with tkinter with a command parameter with an argument I use lambda to do it. (e.g. `Button(root, text="button", command=lambda: function(argument))`)

But what if I want to pass in multiple arguments, or in my case right now two arguments?
When I just put it as `lambda: function(argument1, argument2)`, it gives me an error saying:

```
TypeError: <lambda>() takes no arguments (1 given)
```

How should I do this?

Comment: When I run your code exactly as written, I don't get the error you say you get. Are you getting the error when you do `Button(root, command=lambda: function(argument1, argument2))`, or is the error coming when you are doing a binding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way of using lambdas with several arguments is:

```
lambda arg1, arg2: function(arg1, arg2)
```

see some examples [here](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/07/19/the-python-lambda/) and [here](http://www.ferg.org/thinking_in_tkinter/all_programs.html)